# How to display data using angularJS Loop in 2 separate lines

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to displaying the products using Angular JS loop.

```
<tr ng-repeat="od in OrderDetail">
    <td> {{ od.ProductName }} </td><br />
    <td  align='right'> {{ od.MRP }} </td>
    <td align='right'> {{ od.SellPrice }} </td>
    <td> {{ od.Quantity }} </td>
    <td align='right'> {{ od.Quantity * od.SellPrice | currency:""}}</td>
</tr>
```

My requirement is display the product name in 1 line, then MRP, sellprice, quantity, total in next line... and so on.

I tried  after product name, also i tried using colspan=5 for product name. None of them is working.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: if you want vertical layout why use `<table>`?

Comment: I am not aware about any other way to do it. Can u eloborate on this.

Comment: Well since `<td>` are horzontal why not nested `<div>` or other block elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="od in OrderDetail" >
     <tr>
       <td colspan="4"> {{ od.ProductName }} </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td align='right'> {{ od.MRP }}  </td>
       <td align='right'> {{ od.SellPrice }}</td>
       <td>  {{ od.Quantity }}</td>
       <td align='right'> {{ od.Quantity * od.SellPrice | currency:""}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And yes, it's okay to have more than one `<tbody>`

EDIT: It's good practice to use :: for variables in ngRepeat, if you are only changing the entire array (such as renewing the array) and not modifying elements in the array. This will reduce the amount of watchers needed.

Answer (score 0):

You want `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points